# How to force update child component from parent component in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to re-render child component when parent state is changed

In parent Component in setting up the language
Once language changes child also to be update with the selected languaue

Parent.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Child from "./Child.js";

class Parent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);    
    this.state ={
        lblName: "Name",
        lblGender: "Gender",
        lblDOB: "Date Of Birth",
        lblNatio: "Nationality",
      };
  }
    ChangeLanguage(lang, e){
      if(lang === "en"){
           this.setState(
           {
              lblName: "Name",
              lblGender: "Gender",
              lblDOB: "Date Of Birth",
              lblNatio: "Nationality",
           });
      }
      else if(lang === "sp"){
           this.setState(
           {
              lblName: "Nombre",
              lblGender: "Género",
              lblDOB: "Fecha de nacimiento",
              lblNatio: "Nacionalidad",
           });
      }

    }
    render() {    
    return (
        <Child ChildData={this.state}>
        <button onClick = {this.ChangeLanguage.bind(this, en)}>English</button>
        <button onClick = {this.ChangeLanguage.bind(this, sp)}>Spanish</button>
    )}
}
```

Parent state passing to child and making as child component

Child.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";


class Parent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);    
    this.state = this.props.ChildData;
  }
    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
        this.forceUpdate();
        this.setState(nextProps.ChildData);
    }

    render() {    
    return (
        <div>
             <div>
                  <label>lblName</label>
                  <input type="Text"></input>
             </div>
             <div>
                  <label>lblGender</label>
                  <input type="Text"></input>
             </div>
             <div>
                  <label>lblDOB</label>
                  <input type="Date"></input>
             </div>
             <div>
                  <label>lblNatio</label>
                  <input type="Text"></input>
             </div>
        </div>
    )}
}
```

Tried with these 2 solutions forceUpdate and set the state ... i failed 
I want to update the labels from the parent when ever the language c

Comment: First of all import Child in the Parent component

Answer (score -2, accepted):

child always re-renders when parent does..
use this code for your project

Parent.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Child from './child'

class Parent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);    
    this.state ={
        lblName: "Name",
        lblGender: "Gender",
        lblDOB: "Date Of Birth",
        lblNatio: "Nationality",
      };
  }
    ChangeLanguage(lang, e){
      if(lang === "en"){
           this.setState(
           {
              lblName: "Name",
              lblGender: "Gender",
              lblDOB: "Date Of Birth",
              lblNatio: "Nationality",
           });
      }
      else if(lang === "sp"){
           this.setState(
           {
              lblName: "Nombre",
              lblGender: "Género",
              lblDOB: "Fecha de nacimiento",
              lblNation: "Nacionalidad",
           });
      }

    }
    render() {    
    return (
        <div>
            <Child {...this.state} />
            <button onClick = {this.ChangeLanguage.bind(this, "en")}>English</button>
            <button onClick = {this.ChangeLanguage.bind(this, "sp")}>Spanish</button>
        </div>
    )}
}

export default Parent
```

Child.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Child extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);    
  }
    render() {    
        return (
            <div>
                    <div>
                        <label>{this.props.lblName}</label>
                        <input type="Text"></input>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label>{this.props.lblGender}</label>
                        <input type="Text"></input>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label>{this.props.lblDOB}</label>
                        <input type="Date"></input>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label>{this.props.lblNation}</label>
                        <input type="Text"></input>
                    </div>
            </div>
        )}
}

export default Child
```

Sample index.js file

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import Parent from './parent'

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <Parent />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

for now all the files are in the src folder

Answer (score 2):

Just add Props with language into the child control and pass them from parent

Answer (score 0):

1.) In your Parent.js you should import Child.js
2.) You should export Child and Parent modules at the end of the file
3.) You should use 'en' and 'sp' with apostrophe in the onClick method

1.) Parent.js

```html
import React, {Component} from "react";
import Child from './Child';

class Parent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            lblName: "Name",
            lblGender: "Gender",
            lblDOB: "Date Of Birth",
            lblNatio: "Nationality",
        };
    }

    ChangeLanguage(lang, e) {
        if (lang === "en") {
            this.setState(
                {
                    lblName: "Name",
                    lblGender: "Gender",
                    lblDOB: "Date Of Birth",
                    lblNatio: "Nationality",
                });
        }
        else if (lang === "sp") {
            this.setState(
                {
                    lblName: "Nombre",
                    lblGender: "Género",
                    lblDOB: "Fecha de nacimiento",
                    lblNatio: "Nacionalidad",
                });
        }

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Child ChildData={this.state}/>
                <button onClick={this.ChangeLanguage.bind(this, 'en')}>
                    English
                </button>
                <button onClick={this.ChangeLanguage.bind(this, 'sp')}>Spanish</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}


export default Parent;
```

2. Child.js

```html
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Child extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = this.props.ChildData;
    }
    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
        this.forceUpdate();
        this.setState(nextProps.ChildData);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div>
                    <label>{this.state.lblName}</label>
                    <input type="Text"></input>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>{this.state.lblGender}</label>
                    <input type="Text" ></input>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>{this.state.lblDOB}</label>
                    <input type="Date"></input>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>{this.state.lblNatio}</label>
                    <input type="Text"></input>
                </div>
            </div>
        )}
}

export default Child;
```

Comment: `componentWillReceiveProps` is deprecated